# Multiple windows in Pyglet - only first window draws anything

Tags: python, pyglet

I've been trying to write app with multiple windows in pyglet and no matter what I do only 1 window draws something, other windows show up, but remain black.

This is the simplest code in which the problem exist (it's just template hello world copied twice):

```
import pyglet

window  = pyglet.window.Window()    
label = pyglet.text.Label('Window 1',
                          font_name='Times New Roman',
                          font_size=36,
                          x=window.width//2, y=window.height//2,
                          anchor_x='center', anchor_y='center')    
@window.event
def on_draw():
    window.clear()
    label.draw()

window1  = pyglet.window.Window()
label1 = pyglet.text.Label('Window 2',
                          font_name='Times New Roman',
                          font_size=36,
                          x=window1.width//2, y=window1.height//2,
                          anchor_x='center', anchor_y='center')
@window1.event
def on_draw():
    window1.clear()
    label1.draw()
    
pyglet.app.run()
```

Comment: Sorry, but I cannot reproduce the issue. The code works fine for me (windows, python 3.8, pyglet 1.5.7). What is your python version, pyglet version and OS?

Comment: I have python 3.8.1, on win10, but I had masive problems with pip (It needs reinstalling, can't even reset itself), and istalled pyglet manually, so maybe that means that I just messed that up.afterall.(the rest of pygled worked, so assumed it was good)
I'll be solving the pip issue tommorow (probably reinstal python tbh), reinstall pyglet and tell if it helped

Comment: Issue solved, turns out something was wrong with pyglet installation, thanks for help